# How to create a JavaFX texture

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I can make a rectangle with JavFX like this:

```
Rectangle node2 = RectangleBuilder.create()
            .x(-100)
            .y(-100)
            .width(200)
            .height(200)
            .fill(Color.GREEN)
            .build();
```

but how can I make it use a texture instead of just a color?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the fill to an `ImagePattern`

```
Rectangle node2 = 
  RectangleBuilder.create()
    .x(-100)
    .y(-100)
    .width(200)
    .height(200)
    .fill(
      new ImagePattern(
        new Image("file:flower.png"), 0, 0, 1, 1, true
      )
    )
    .build();
```

There are additional samples in the [ImagePattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html).

For JavaFX8, you will also be able to do this [via css](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19455).

Comment: Thanks. How does it find the image? Where would I put the image for it to find it? It seems to need a full path. Can it find using the normal resource path?

Comment: Ah yes, my one and only question on StackOverflow to date: [Where does javafx.scene.image.Image(“flower.png”) look for flower.png?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575410/where-does-javafx-scene-image-imageflower-png-look-for-flower-png)