# How to clip an Image when JavaFX ImageView will not display Image

Tags: java, image, javafx-2, fxml

I have a GIF image file that I was displaying in an ImageView with JavaFX.  I am allowing administrators to change the logo file and I want to ensure it scales correctly to fit the display area.  I had it all working until I had a file that was a bit taller than wide and taller than the **fitHeight**.

When the file is not a *happy size*, the image does NOT display.  I'd like some suggestions for a fall-back strategy.  My preferred options are:

- Detect if the image will fail-to-display after the **ImageView**.**setImage**() method

  - I can then reload the image and change the fitHeight to a known *safe value* and issue a warning, or
- Force the image to display so that it is clipped to the fitWidth and fitHeight
- Keep the previous image if the file is incompatible

  - Reuse the previous image by saving: **this.logo.getImage()**
  - Trick question: How do I know the image does not display / will be incompatible?
- I wondered if there's an event that I can check to verify/fix an image load?

I'm open to alternative strategy suggestions.  For a bit of context the logo image is specified by a URL via a config file and an FXML that is loaded at (unattended) boot time.  We can't have a blank box on-screen something needs to be done if there's a problem displaying an image.

I can't identify a JavaFX call to inform me if the image is actually visible after the **setImage**() call. To be fair the scene refresh happens after this.

I have identified the source of the The following the top line works:

```
 <ImageView fx:id="logo" fitHeight="320.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
```

This version fails to display:

```
 <ImageView fx:id="logo" fitHeight="360.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
```

fitHeight values under about 350 work, determined by experimentation.  When fitHeight is too high, the image is invisible (not displayed).

possibly **related**:

- [ImageView in javaFx is not shown when i run it as webstart or in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889096/imageview-in-javafx-is-not-shown-when-i-run-it-as-webstart-or-in-browser)

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful: (Using various properties of `Image` itself): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html

Comment: @Forager, yes I looked at the image -- Actually that _is_ the question.  How can I determine the Image attributes for the specific ImageView so that I can load the image such that it will be clipped, scrolled or resized depending on the use-case.  I can do resize, but clipping doesn't seem to behave.  Also the when it not clipped it can and does *vanish* -- so we need to know if the image has _vanished_ and take corrective action!

Comment: By image clipping, do you mean displaying as is, while cutting off anything that goes off-window, or do you mean resizing the image? I can't say I fully understand what's causing your issue, but it seems like you understand it to be a problem with image size. Is the `isError()` method not applicable for your case?

Comment: This is a FXML scene using Java JavaFX 2.  The question is about the ImageView JavaFX control, not the Image object.  The image object is perfectly "_fine_".  Even if it worked (and it doesn't) isError would not tell me IF something displayed, hidden or had been clipped, scroll/overflow or chopped.