# Javafx image path

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

What will be the picture.jpg absolute image path and relative image path for the following directory structure?

### Directory structure

```
JavaProject  
    |_Package1  
    |    |_App1.java
    |
    |_Package2
         |
       PICS
         |_picture.jpg
```

### Code

```
public class App1 extends Application{
    ...
    Image picturePath = new Image( ??? );
    ImageView picture = new ImageView(picturePath);
    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot load image in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099427/cannot-load-image-in-javafx)

Comment: My bad! I made the directory structure wrong. The Pics directory should be in another Java Project directory. I know how to create image path if the PICS directory locates under the same project directory. But I don't know how to create a path for the PICS directory locates at different project directory.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute path, relative to your project is :

```
Image picturePath = new Image("/Package2/Picture/picture.jpg");
```

If you need a path relative to the class file, you may use :

```
Image picturePath = new Image("../Package2/Picture/picture.jpg");
```