# JavaFx Image not found in Jar file

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm trying to generate a runnable jar file of my project which has a JavaFx gui.
The project runs greate in eclipse but whenI try to run the jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   ...Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
```

The code for the images looks like:

```
private Image image1 = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../pic/classic/image1.png"));
```

What do I need to change so that i can run my jar file with no exception.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do not use `..` in the String.  If there is a class in the parent package, use that as a reference for the resource:  `SomeClassInParentPackage.class.getResourceAsStream("pic/classic/image1.png")`  Otherwise, just refer to the resource with a root-relative resource path: `"/com/example/app/pic/classic/image1.png"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16122215/5969411

Comment: *"EDIT: Thanks for the help on the first question.
another question how can I ..."* No, you got your answer to the question. Do not edit your question to add more questions. I rolled back that edit for this reason. You can still find your content here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38444852/revisions . Please ask a new question. Also if the answer works for you, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 7):

The `..` is not valid in specifying a resource name in a jar file. According to the [documentation on resource naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) each component of the resource path should be a valid Java identifier: `..` is not.

To fix this, just specify the absolute resource name, relative to the classpath. So if the class you are in is in a package called `com.mycompany.myapplication.view`, you would use

```
private Image image1 = 
    new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/myapplication/pic/classic/image1.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that image file names are CASE SENSITIVE within jar and are not in IDE (e.g. Eclipse).

So if you have `"/resource/image.jpg"` argument and `IMAGE.jpg` filename, application will work in Eclipse and, being exported to jar, will produce `NullPointerException` in

```
Image image1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/image.jpg"));
```