# Java Source in many Directorys above

Tags: java, image, file, javafx, directory

i have a JavaFX project with many packages. i wanted to create a folder with all my icons within. the icon path is: src/icon/test.png and my class, where i try to initialize my Image, is: src/project/menus/ressources/settings/SettingWindow.java.
my problem is, that i am not able to get to the root folder, into the icon folder.

here is my source for the SettingWindow:

```
package project.menus.ressources.settings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SettingWindow{

    @FXML private TextField nameTF;
    @FXML private Button pinButton;

    private Stage stage;


    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;

/*-----------------Here where i try to initialize the Image -------------*/
        Image icon = new Image("file: /icon/test.png", 25,25, false, false);

        pinButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(icon));
    }
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
    public TextField getNameField() {
        return this.nameTF;
    }


}
```

"file: /icon/test.png" is not the only thing i tried. i found somewhere a solution to get the root directory with getRoot() but i couldnt use this method.
I cant use the AbsolutPath to the folder, because its planed to use this software on different PC's

Comment: The String "file: /icon/test.png" is not a valid URL, nor is going to be a valid location on the file system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot load image in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099427/cannot-load-image-in-javafx)

Comment: If your icons are _resources_ you should not be using a `file:` URL.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most flexible approach for finding resources is to use an `InputStream` and allow the classloader to find the object. So, based upon the statement that the resource (the image) is in the `src` folder, and presuming that said `src` folder is fully added to the classpath, then something like the following might work.

Note: I am assuming the `.setGraphic(new ImageView(icon))` is correct -- I'm not overly familiar with JavaFX.

```
private void loadAndDisplayImage(Button btn) {
  final String name = "icon/test.png";
  ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    //
    // use the try with resources, and allow the classloader to find the resource
    //   on the classpath, and return the input stream
    //
    try (InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream(name)) {
      // the javafx Image accepts an inputstream, with width, height, ratio, smoot
      Image icon = new Image(is, 25, 25, false, false);

      // should probably ensure icon is not null, but presumably if the resource
      //   was found, it is loaded properly, so OK to set the image
      btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(icon));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then call the `loadAndDisplayImage(pinButton);` method from the `setStage(...)`

I think this approach is a bit more flexible than trying to code the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do not expect the source directory to be available at runtime the same way they were before building your program.

Often the compilation results are compressed with the resources to a `jar` file. The contents of a jar file are not accessible via the file system. Instead you should use a `Class.getResource` get the url of a resource and pass it to the `Image` constructor. (This only works if the resources are available via classpath, but if they are available, it works whether they are packed in a jar or not):

```
Image icon = new Image(SettingWindow.class.getResource("/icon/test.png").toExternalForm(),
                       25, 25, false, false);
```