# JavaFX image nullpointerexception

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to declare an Image object, but I get a NullPointerException every time I try to use it.  This is my constructor:

```
final Image systemSecureImage = new Image((getClass().getResource("images/notifications/systemSecure.png")).toString());
```

When I try to use it in a method, it throws the error.  For example...

```
sample.sampleMethod(image);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I've also tried it two other ways:

```
Image systemSecureImage = new Image("images/notifications/systemSecure.png");
Image systemSecureImage = new Image("file://images/notifications/systemSecure.png");
```

Comment: Have a look at [jewelsea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea)'s [first and only question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575410/where-does-javafx-scene-image-imageflower-png-look-for-flower-png) :-)

Comment: this issue is solved in jdk 1.8...try latest jdk

Answer (score 1):

The `Image`'s constructor needs the external form of the resource path.

```
final Image systemSecureImage = new Image((getClass().getResource("images/notifications/systemSecure.png")).toExternalForm());
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the NullPointerException is thrown due to the image?
If the line

```
sample.sampleMethod(image);
```

throws that NPE, it is because `sample` is null, i.e. not initiated. Observe the exception stacktrace carefully and determine exactly at which line the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new source folder in order for javafx to find your image; this worked for me in javafx 2 as well as in javafx 8.

Say you have that project:

```
project/src
project/lib
project/img
project/img/image.png
```

just right click on the `img` folder in eclipse -> Build Path -> Use as source folder
Your image would then be like: new Image("image.png");

Hope it helps,
Laurenz

Comment: I'm actually using NetBeans.  Is there something similar I would have to do with it?

Comment: I am not using Netbeans, but if I'm not mistaken this should work out for you: Right Click on your Project -> Click 'Properties'-> Then you should see 'Sources' highlighted -> Click 'Add folder...' where it says 'Source package folders'