# ImageView doesn't load image in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

This is a simple code to display image using JavaFX. However, my image can't load at all, even though I have run "Build and Clean" code.

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    Image image = new Image("file: images/knives.jpg");
    System.out.println("Is loaded: " + image.isError());

    //Add image to pane
    HBox pane = new HBox(10);
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

    //Add pane to scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    //Add things to stage
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Image image = new Image("/images/knives.jpg");

Comment: other than give to full path ex "file:///home/reegan/temp/serialObservable/trunk/src/main/java/main/2-user-group-icon.png"

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575410/where-does-javafx-scene-image-imageflower-png-look-for-flower-png

Answer (score 0):

```
package imageloaded;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class ImageLoaded extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Image image = new Image("/images/Javafx_logo_color.png");
        System.out.println("Is loaded: " + image.isError());

        //Add image to pane
        HBox pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

        //Add pane to scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        //Add things to stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
//       
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Create images folder in under src. like

```
reegan@toad:~/NetBeansProjects/ImageLoaded/src$ ls
imageloaded  images
reegan@toad:~/NetBeansProjects/ImageLoaded/src/imageloaded$ ls
ImageLoaded.java
reegan@toad:~/NetBeansProjects/ImageLoaded/src/images$ ls
Javafx_logo_color.png
```

Other than you have used in file:

```
Image image = new Image("file:///home/reegan/NetBeansProjects/ImageLoaded/src/images/Javafx_logo_color.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However, it didn't seem to work for me, w/wo putting the image folder under src. 
I do have another application that work just fine with images folder not under src.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. use System.getPropery("user.dir") to get the application location
2. append the location of your image file eg. **image.gif** . Suppose image.gif is inside **src/sample/images** which are packages, then following code should work.

   String appMain = System.getProperty("user.dir");

   System.out.println(appMain);

   Image image = new Image("file:"+appMain+"/src/sample/images/image.gif");

   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, the images were there -- in the `SceneBuilder` (I was using `NetBeans 8.2`), but the application when run did not show them. Solution in my case? In the `SceneBuilder`, toggle "Switch to absolute paths" next to the image's location.