# Display Image on imageview JavaFx

Tags: java, image, netbeans, javafx, imageview

I have a  .fxml file with some empty rectangules inside a grind

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="650.0"     styleClass="fondo2" stylesheets="@tablerolote.css"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="juegoloto.CartonController">


    <children>
          <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="44.0"     prefHeight="614.0" prefWidth="474.0" styleClass="fondo">
            <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"    />    
             <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
               <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <ImageView id="1" fitHeight="127.0" fitWidth="93.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <ImageView id="2" fitHeight="127.0" fitWidth="96.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <ImageView id="3" fitHeight="126.0" fitWidth="96.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <ImageView id="4" fitHeight="127.0" fitWidth="97.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />

         </children>
      </GridPane>

   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

it was created automatically with netbeans (drag and drop interface), how do i send and image to display in the `ImageView id="2" /ImageView id="3"` etc, from the .java file

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Carton.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);


    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

i also have a controller.java file but i dont know what to do with it

```
public class CartonController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

Comment: Set the images from your [controller class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this in the controller class. How to use controllers is described in full in the [FXML reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers), but in short:

Put an `fx:id` on the `ImageView`s (you can do this in SceneBuilder):

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="650.0"     styleClass="fondo2" stylesheets="@tablerolote.css"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="juegoloto.CartonController">


    <children>
          <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="44.0"     prefHeight="614.0" prefWidth="474.0" styleClass="fondo">
            <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"    />    
             <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
               <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"     prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <ImageView id="1" fx:id="imageView1" fitHeight="127.0" fitWidth="93.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <ImageView id="2" fx:id="imageView2" fitHeight="127.0" fitWidth="96.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <ImageView id="3" fx:id="imageView3" fitHeight="126.0" fitWidth="96.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <ImageView id="4"  fx:id="imageView4" fitHeight="127.0" fitWidth="97.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />

         </children>
      </GridPane>

   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Then inject these into your controller and you can access them as needed:

```
public class CartonController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ImageView imageView1 ;

@FXML
private ImageView imageView2 ;

@FXML
private ImageView imageView3 ;

@FXML
private ImageView imageView4 ;    

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        imageView1.setImage(new Image(...));
        // etc...
    }    

}
```

Comment: Hi! thank for your answer, but i stll have a problem , in the initialize method ///  

    File file = new File("1.jpg");
        
        if(file.exists()){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            carta1.setImage(image);
        }else{
            System.out.println("File not found");
            }

/// i have that, and i get a message saying that the file not found, and the image is in the same directory with the rest of the files :/

Comment: That's a different question, which is already addressed many times on SO. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305037/javafx-images-path

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method to retrieve the `ImageView`:

```
public ImageView findById(AnchorPane root, String id) {
  for (Node child : root.getChildren()) {
    if (child instanceof ImageView && child.getId().equals(id)) {
      return (ImageView)child;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This method will iterate through all direct children of the root `AnchorPane` and check the `ImageView` node for it's ID. If no matching node is found, null will be returned. From there you can use the `setImage` method on the returned `ImageView`.