# IllegalArgumentException : image must be non-null

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8

I'm working on a simple "Space Invaders" game using JavaFx, and while my game works fine without any exceptions or errors when I run the project inside netbeans, it keeps giving me this error when I run the .jar file through CMD and I can't seem to find a solution.

//this is an example of how i define my images/imagepattern

```java
Image il=new Image("file:ship.png");
setFill(new ImagePattern(il));
```

// this is the error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image must be non-null
        at com.sun.prism.paint.ImagePattern.<init>(ImagePattern.java:44)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createImagePatternPaint(QuantumToolkit.java:905)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getPaint(Toolkit.java:657)
        at javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern.acc_getPlatformPaint(ImagePattern.java:291)
        at javafx.scene.paint.Paint$1.getPlatformPaint(Paint.java:51)
        at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.updatePGShape(Shape.java:916)
        at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.impl_updatePeer(Shape.java:965)
        at javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle.impl_updatePeer(Rectangle.java:541)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_syncPeer(Node.java:503)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2304)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2313)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2280)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2419)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$408(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT:**
after some debugging i have found that the .jar looks for the images in C:\Users\Admin instead of within the project itself, how can i change that?

Comment: Have you tried `new Image("ship.png");` without the `file:` part!?

Comment: make sure your image is included into the jar

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575410/where-does-javafx-scene-image-imageflower-png-look-for-flower-png

Comment: I did try new Image("ship.png") and my images are included in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the image should be in the same directory as your java project or declare a package of icons inside your project.
e.g.: `/icons/monimage.png` in the source directory
otherwise your access path will tighten

```
Image il=new Image("/icon/monimage.png");
setFill(new ImagePattern(il));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void SetImage(ImageView imgV, String patch) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(patch);
    Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString(), imgV.getFitHeight(), imgV.getFitWidth(), true, true);
    imgV.setImage(image);
    imgV.setPreserveRatio(true);
}
```

You can use this function to display an image directly in an ImagaView